# Запуск background процессов в Symfony

Tags: symfony2, background-task, backgroundworker

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста.
Стоит задача внутри контроллера Симфони запускать фоновую задачу, которая бы выполнялась автономно. Внутри контроллера ожидать завершения не нужно. Нужна лишь интеграция с кодом бандла приложения (доступ в БД, к сервисам и прочее).
Пытался юзать Gearman Job Server http://gearman.org/ , но он не реализован для PHP7. Может есть что-то подобное для PHP7 с бандлом для Симфони?

Comment: Добавлю, что таких процессов в один момент времени может быть много, выполняться они должны параллельно. То есть менеджер очередей здесь не подходит.

Comment: что мешает вам использовать интеграцию с более ранней версией? разве семерка не совместима обратно? почему вы думаете, что gearman не является менеджером очереди и что очередь не позволит параллельное выполнение?

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите любой сервер очередей, например тот же RabbitMQ — к нему даже бандл есть, с которым очень легко реализовать консьюмера: https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle — он должен быть совместим с PHP7. В веб-приложении в очередь бросаете сообщение, в консьюмере выполняете работу.

Не знаю, почему «менеджер очередей здесь не подходит» — консьюмеров может быть несколько, выполняться они будут тоже независимо.

Ну или в крайнем случае складывайте задачи в БД и напишите воркера, который будет эти задачи оттуда вылавливать, выполнять и помечать выполненными, но придется реализовать блокировки как-то.